# How keras.utils.Sequence works?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, oop, keras

I am trying to create a data pipeline for U-net for Image Segmentation. I came across `Keras.utils.Sequence` class through which, I can create a data pipeline, But I am unable to understand how this is working.

link for the code [Keras code](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) , [Source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/data_utils.py)

```
  def __iter__(self):
    """Create a generator that iterate over the Sequence."""
    for item in (self[i] for i in range(len(self))):
      yield item
```

I will highly appreciate if anyone can tell me how this works ?

Answer (score 11):

You don't need a generator. The sequence class is there to manage that. You need to define a class inherited from `tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence` and define the methods:
`__init__`, `__getitem__`, `__len__`. In addition, you can define the method `on_epoch_end`, which is called at the end of each epoch and is usually used to shuffle the sample indexes.
There is an example in the link you gave [Tensorflow Sequence](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence).
Below is another example of Sequence.
Note that you can pass the data to the `__init__` constructor, but you may as well read the data from files in the `__getitem__` method, assuming you know where to read it, e.g. by passing the name of a directory or directories into the constructor. This is necessary if there is a lot of data.

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

class SequenceExample(keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_in, y_in, batch_size, shuffle=True):
        # Initialization
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.x = x_in
        self.y = y_in
        self.datalen = len(y_in)
        self.indexes = np.arange(self.datalen)
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # get batch indexes from shuffled indexes
        batch_indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        x_batch = self.x[batch_indexes]
        y_batch = self.y[batch_indexes]
        return x_batch, y_batch
    
    def __len__(self):
        # Denotes the number of batches per epoch
        return self.datalen // self.batch_size

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        # Updates indexes after each epoch
        self.indexes = np.arange(self.datalen)
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
```

Comment: In case someone is wondering how to pass this into kears' fit, you can pass argument as `model.fit(x=SequenceExample(...))`. There is no need to provide values for `y` and `batch_size` as it can directly be extracted from `SequenceExample` instance automatically.